# Getting "receipt invalid" error on iOS when testing using Storekit configuration file and Revenuecat

Tags: ios, storekit, revenuecat

Im trying to test staging and production apps separately on iOS. To do this, I created separate targets with separate bundle ids. Im using RevenueCat to help with subscriptions so I followed the guidelines here:

https://community.revenuecat.com/general%2Dquestions%2D7/how%2Dshould%2Di%2Duse%2Dmy%2Dstaging%2Dapp%2Dwith%2Drevenue%2Dcat%2Dbundle%2Did%2Dmismatch%2D1181

Since I only need to test locally on device and on the simulator, I created a StoreKit configuration file and downloaded the cert. I then created a separate project in Revenue Cat with the staging app bundle ID (I already had one with my production app), the app secret from AppStoreConnect, the Storekit cert, and the products setup to match the Storekit configuration file.

I’ve double checked to ensure that in the bundleID matches the bundleID in XCode. I’ve also checked to ensure that the products setup match the products in the StoreKit config file. But, when I try to complete a purchase in my staging app, I get the following error

ERROR:  Product purchase for '(product' failed with error: Error Domain=RevenueCat.ErrorCode Code=8 "The receipt is not valid."

If I click the button a second time it tells me I have already made the purchase before and “subscription will renew on ..”.

I've posted on the RC forum but received no response. Any help would be appreciated!

Any help would be appreciated!